# Оформление диалога в виде прямой речи

Tags: пунктуация

Бывают ситуации, когда надо описать диалог в виде прямой речи, а не собственно диалога. Например, такой текст: "«Куда тебе?» — «Симферополь». Я ему в шутку: «3000 рублей, устроит? За час домчу!» — «Едем!»"
Я поставила между репликами тире, но совершенно не уверена, что сделала правильно. Но просто не знала, как нужно пунктуационно оформлять такой диалог. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это оформление диалога в строку (в подбор). Между репликами ставится ТИРЕ, если ВСТРЕЧАЕТСЯ прямая речь разных авторов; в противном случае тире не ставится. Если исходить из этого правила, то знаки препинания поставлены правильно.