# Как оформить полилог в мыслях героя?

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь, редактура, диалог

Помогите, пожалуйста, оформить полилог в мыслях медитирующего героя.

> Зельд присел подле камушка и прислушался к тому, что говорилось на
> этом месте с момента его отъезда… В шуме слов и мыслей его задела лишь
> радость по поводу выплаченной премии.
>
> «Возиться пришлось долго» — «Надо же такое ляпнуть светлейшему» — «Все
> хорошо, что хорошо кончается» — «Особенно если это не твоя смерть под
> камнями»…
>
> Тут Зельд прервал контакт: он отчетливо услышал имя своего ученика.

Comment: Оформление диалога: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/40254/%d0%9e%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b8

Answer (score 1):

> «Возиться пришлось долго» — «Надо же такое ляпнуть светлейшему» — «Все
>   хорошо, что хорошо кончается» — «Особенно если это не твоя смерть под
>   камнями»…

— Возиться пришлось долго. — Надо же такое ляпнуть светлейшему. — Все хорошо, что хорошо кончается. — Особенно если это не твоя смерть под камнями...

— Возиться пришлось долго... Надо же такое ляпнуть светлейшему... Все хорошо, что хорошо кончается... Особенно если это не твоя смерть под камнями...

— Возиться пришлось долго.., надо же такое ляпнуть светлейшему.., все хорошо, что хорошо кончается.., особенно если это не твоя смерть под камнями...

— Возитьсяпришлосьдолго.., надожетакоеляпнутьсветлейшему.., всехорошочтохорошокончается.., особенноеслиэтонетвоясмертьподкамнями...

Comment: shampar, вы преднамерено написали слитно или это случайно получилось?

Comment: Этот  вариант — намёк на речитатив, слово, монотонно переходящее в другое.

Answer (score 1):

1. Я поняла так: и слова, и чужие мысли Зельд слышит одновременно.
2. Текст явно фантастический (или сказочный), поэтому, думаю, возможно написание *Светлейший* (это, конечно, зависит от контекста).
3. Я ориентировалась вот на этот отрывок (кому конкретно принадлежат произнесенные в тексте слова – непонятно):

*– (...) Трудно ли принять решение?

Поднялся гул голосов, звучало:

– Стоит ли рассуждать? Он умрёт от зимних дождей; солнце сожжёт его! Какой вред может принести нам безволосая лягушка? Пусть себе бегает со стаей. А где бык, Багира? Примем детёныша!*
[**Р. Киплинг. Маугли**](https://mybook.ru/author/redyard-kipling/maugli/read/?page=2)

Зельд присел подле камушка и прислушался к тому, что говорилось на этом месте с момента его отъезда… В шуме чужих слов и мыслей его задела лишь радость по поводу выплаченной премии.

Вперемешку доносилось [или звучало, или раздавалось, или улавливалось]:
– Возиться пришлось долго. Надо же такое ляпнуть Светлейшему. Все хорошо, что хорошо кончается. Особенно если это не твоя смерть под камнями...

Тут Зельд прервал контакт: он отчетливо услышал имя своего ученика.

Comment: Римма, Светлейший вас благодарит. И автор тоже. Вы миротворец.)))

Comment: Э-э... растерялась. И вам спасибо за оценку. Мне самой было интересно искать варианты - такие "фигуры" встречаются нечасто.

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, это не беседа, а набор реплик. Не думаю, что такое прописано в учебниках. Может, дать их в кавычках через запятую?

**Зельд присел подле камушка и прислушался к тому, что говорилось на этом месте с момента его отъезда: «Возиться пришлось долго…», «Надо же такое ляпнуть светлейшему…», «Все хорошо, что хорошо кончается…», «Особенно если это не твоя смерть под камнями…» В шуме слов и мыслей его задела лишь радость по поводу выплаченной премии. Но тут Зельд прервал контакт: он отчетливо услышал имя своего ученика.**